# Using exit and a global object

Tags: c++

I have the following program where i am calling exit() in the destructor. When i create an object of type sample inside main() destructor is called once and program exits normally. But when i create a global object of type sample, "Destructing.." gets printed infinitely. Can anyone please explain how?

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;

class sample
{
      public:
     ~sample() {
                    cout <<"Destructing.."<<endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
};

sample obj;

int main()
{
 getch();   
}
```

Comment: probably you are using turboc, please avoid it, and do not use conio.h functions.

Comment: M using Dev-C++ . It uses GCC compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening is, the `exit()` function is getting the program to call destructors on all of the global objects.  And since at the point where your class's destructor calls `exit(1);` the object is not yet considered to be destructed, the destructor gets called again, resulting in an infinite loop.

You could get away with this:

```
class sample {
    bool exiting;
public:
    sample() { exiting = false; }
    ~sample() {
        cout << "Destructing.." << endl;
        if(exiting) return;
        exiting = true;
        exit(0);
    }
};
```

But having a destructor call `exit()` is a Bad Idea.  consider one of these alternatives:

- create a separate normal (non-destructor) method for exiting
- create a function that runs until the "program" is finished and call it from `main()`
- use `abort()` instead of `exit()` (Thanks goldilocks for mentioning this one).  `abort()` bypasses all of the cleaning up that is normally done when `exit()` is called and when `main()` returns.  However this is not necessarily a good idea either, as certain cleanup operations in your program could be quite critical.  `abort()` is meant only for errors that are already so bad that bypassing cleanup is warranted.

I suggested exceptions before but remembered about throwing exceptions from inside destructors and changed my mind. [here's why.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.9)

Note also, the behavior is not consistent - some compilers/environments result in an infinite loop, some don't.  It comes down to at which point in the destructor the object is considered to be destroyed.  I would guess the standard either doesn't cover this or says the behavior in this case is undefined.

Comment: why i do not get the same effects as the asker ?

Comment: because your compiler is smarter, perhaps

Comment: even with `-O0` with `gcc` i get one line printed.

Comment: also, if it prints multiple lines for global, why not local then.

Comment: local destructors are called when their function exits.  I will expand to cover that.

Comment: You mean that for local objects their destructors will be called when their scope exits, whereas exit() calls the destructors for all global objects?

Comment: @MichaelSlade What do you mean by __use exceptions__? Throwing an exception from a destructor could cause [`terminate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/exception/terminate/) to be called.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Micheal Slade that doing that in a destructor is a sign of bad design.  But if you think you have a good reason to do so (eg, development issue), use `abort()` instead of `exit(0)`.  This will prevent any more destructors from being called and get you out of the recursive loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your destructing destructor calls exit which in turn calls the destruction destructor which calls exit which in turn calls ... (Yes, it goes on for a very long time).