# Using exit() in destructor of a class having static object, doesn't end up in an infinite loop as expected

Tags: c++, static, destructor, exit, static-members

I came across this in chapter 10, Thinking in C++ vol.1 by Bruce Eckel.

> Destructors for static objects (that is, all objects with static storage, not just local static objects as in the example above) are called when main( ) exits or when the Standard C library function exit( ) is explicitly called. In most implementations, main( ) just calls exit( ) when it terminates. This means that it can be dangerous to call exit( ) inside a destructor because you can end up with infinite recursion

I also came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10379108/using-exit-and-a-global-object) in SO.
Then, I wrote a code myself to simulate this recursion but I failed. Here's how my code looks like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Test
{
    private:
        std::string _name;
        static Test obj1;
        static Test obj2;
    public:
        Test(std::string name)
        {
            std::cout << "in constructor:" << name << std::endl;
            _name = name;
        }
        ~Test()
        {
            std::cout << "in destructor:" << _name << std::endl;
            if ("class static 2" == _name)
            {
                std::cout << "calling exit" << std::endl;
                exit(2);
                std::cout << "should not print this" << std::endl;
            }
        }
};

Test global("global");
Test Test::obj1("class static 1");
Test Test::obj2("class static 2");

int main(void)
{
    static Test mainStatic_1("main static");

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output I got, without any infinite looping

```
in constructor:global
in constructor:class static 1
in constructor:class static 2
in constructor:main static
in destructor:main static
in destructor:class static 2
calling exit
in destructor:class static 1
in destructor:global
```

Is my compiler smart enough to handle this? I am using GCC 4.7.2 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this comes under the heading of "undefined behaviour". I can't find a paragraph in the C++ standard to say so, but it's pretty obvious that if you call `exit()` from something that happened because you called `exit()`, chances are that you end up in an infinite loop. It is not guaranteed, because the handling of the global destructors may be done in such a way that the list of things to destroy is dealt with by first removing it from some the list [1], then calling the destructor. So if `exit` is called again, it will be in a state where it "has already dealt with this object".

The standard certainly doesn't say "You must cope with `exit()` being called multiple times - so it's quite possible that another C++ library will fail to cope with this.

And being pedantic: It's not so much the compiler as the C++ or classic C runtime library that deals with this.

[1] By list, I'm not saying `std::list`, but a generic "Some sort of container holding what needs to be destroyed".

Answer (score 1):

> Is my compiler smart enough to handle this?

It would appear that they have added some safeguards for it, but it is still a bad practice nonetheless.